# JavaFX: How to be notified when a Property is no longer reachable?

Tags: clojure, javafx

I'm writing a bunch of JavaFX (8.0) code in Clojure (1.6) on Windows x64.

My domain/application data is a nested Clojure hash-map that lives in a ref/atom, and I wish to tie specific sub-elements of the map to one or more UI elements.  Call this big map `global-var`.  I do not wish to maintain my domain data as a bunch of JFX Properties, since this was the whole point of using Clojure and its data structures and functions, so I'm not considering using JFX `Bind...` functions to tie UI elements to my domain data.  I'm only dealing with JFX Properties as they exist naturally inside JFX objects and trying not to create more.

To implement the "observable" pattern, I have a `ChangeListener` on each JFX Property (such as the `textProperty` of a `TableCell` inside a `TableView`) which updates the entire global-var.

To notify the various properties of changes to global-var, I also do `add-watch` on the global-var for each property receiving change notification, with some special cases to prevent infinite looping.

The problem is *un*registering watches.  In the case of `TableView`, the JFX engine creates new cells all the time -- at least twice just for showing the window, and evidently at least twice every time I update the `global-var`.

Specifically, following the various examples I've found, when the column's `TableCell`'s `updateItem` method is called, I create a new graphic element for that cell.  This allows me a different cell type for each row within a column, rather than the default where each cell in a column is the same.  So every time the cell is updated, a new (proxy of) TableCell is created, and a new watch is added to the global-var.

I don't mind constantly creating new objects since the JVM is supposed to be good at garbage collection, but I'm annoyed that with each new UI element I'm adding an additional watch to the `global-var`, with no mechanism to know when to do `remove-watch`.  Even with a single property, the number of watches increments (without bound) each time the data changes, because of how TableView works.

There are some special cases possible based on the `Stage`'s `onCloseRequest`, but these don't apply in the case of `TableView`.

So the question is, Is there a way of finding when a JFX `Property` is no longer accessible, either through some type of destructor, event, callback, or other notification, such that I may `remove-watch`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are reused. In `updateItem`, first clean up after the old item and then set it up for the new item. I don't know how `add-watch`/`remove-watch` works in Clojure, but here is the skeleton for your `updateItem` method:

```
public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    removeOldWatch(); // whatever that means

    addWatch(); // whatever that means
}
```